# What kinds of misc (implement, ki focus, that sort of thing) items can a swordmage equip?

Tags: dnd-4e, swordmage

I am playing a swordmage, and have 620 gp. My DM decided to open the shop so that we can buy some items with our cash. I don't know what I can actually use though.

Comment: Okay, are you asking what gear is appropriate for a swordmage? Or are you asking what implements he can use? What level are you, what's your build, what's "tons?" and are there any other limitations on purchasing other than price?

Comment: @Brian    I'm asking what gear is appropriate, yes.    I'm level 4 and have 620gp (our dm isn't terribly giving, that's my savings from the entire time from level 1-4)   The only limitation is "no mounts"

Comment: That was fast. Okay, 620 gp... changes things. What feats do you have? How many close burst powers, how many melee powers? What is your aegis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An abstract answer can be found [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22198629/Masters_of_Blade_Magic%3a_A_Swordmage_Handbook) in the equipment recommendations. Swordmages, by default, can only use heavy blades as implements. Happily, there are a fair number of heavy blades designed for swordmages. My favourite would be Gith Silver, simply because I like psychic lock. A -2 on top of a -2 from marks for one *nasty* defender. It keeps you alive longer as well.

Reach extenders are cute, especially with an item set devoted to it (Arcane Bonds) but require specialized builds. Swordmages are *hurting* for damage, and if you're a melee-focused build IAoP are pretty critical. "Rhythm Blade Wrist Razors (AV2/DSCS, lvl. 3) - This is a very nice way to get the benefit of the Rhythm Blade (+1 AC/Ref) without losing the +3 bonus to AC from your warding."

Edit

With 620 gp, you can afford a level 1 or level 2 item. If you don't have a +1 weapon, buy a Magic +1 weapon. If you don't have +1 Armor, buy +1 Armor, and if you don't have +1 neck, buy a +1 neck. Level 2 items are just not that impressive and burning the rest on a couple of healing potions is very much worth it.

If you find yourself doing the defender-dance (prone every other turn) a pair of acrobat boots isn't bad, but only if you have +1 in your 3 primary slots.

Edit:

To answer the question of the title: Most of them. Just like every other character, you have: head, arms(bracers, since shields break your warding), neck, armor, feet, ring, ring, ki-focus (not used), holy symbol (not used), Tattoo (look at level 3), Boon (kinda not really slotted, but I've never heard of someone having more than one), Waist, and other. There are entirely too many items out there. My personal recommendation is to ask your DM to go to intrinsic bonuses and item rarity, *simply* to cut down on the stupid numbers of items you'll want to choose from. While this is less critical at low levels, high level item selection is just not fun for anyone (that I've heard).

Comment: Okay, thank you.      I know 620 isn't "alot" but that was literally all we got in a whole campaign.     I shall go for the armor.

Comment: Cool. It's a decent investment for a defender.